# Problems linking gsl 2.1 with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, gsl

I'm using Qt 5.8 and gsl 2.1 (compiled with cygwin64). This is what I use in the .pro file to link gsl:

```
INCLUDEPATH+=C:/gsl/include/
INCLUDEPATH += C:/gsl/LIBS
LIBS += -LC:/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

When I include the headers and compile, I don't have any problem, even when I declare and object. But when I try to use any function I get this error:

```
C:\Users\CIFAS-1\untitled4\mainwindow.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to `gsl_matrix_alloc'.
```

Comment: try with `"path"`, ie `INCLUDEPATH+="C:/gsl/include/"`

Comment: the problem isn't the include the problems is linking in runtime. I think I need a dll, but when I compiled when cygwin it doesn't generated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve the problem, I found a compiled version of gsl for mingw32 here https://code.google.com/archive/p/gsl-w32/downloads, it is another version but works great.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.